# Find a differential equation for $w(t) = \phi_t(z) = \frac{z+ \tan t}{1 - z(\tan t)}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a differential equation for $w(t) = \phi_t(z) = \frac{z+ \tan t}{1 - z(\tan t)}$.

Usually the question is the other way around, but (D. H. Sattinger and O. L. Weaver, 1986 Lie Groups and Algebras with Applications to Physics, Geometry, and Mechanics) pose it like this.

Earlier we showed that $\phi_{t+s} = \phi_{t}\circ\phi_{s}$.

Since $\text{tan}$ is a periodic function, I thing that the differential equation they are looking for might be of order 2.

My efforts so far consists of calculating $w'(t)$, and trying to identify $w$ in there, but things get messy.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like the following:

$$\begin{align} w(\tan(x)) &= \frac {\tan(x) + \tan(t)}{1 - \tan(x)\tan(t)} \\
&= \tan(x+t).\end{align}$$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$, using that $\tan'(x) = 1 + tan^2(x)$, this becomes

$$ w'(\tan(x))(1 + \tan^2(x)) = 1 + \tan^2(x+t),$$

i.e.,

$$ w'(z)(1 + z^2) = 1 + (w(z))^2.$$

Will this do? In fact, if there are no restrictions on what kind of a differential equation you need, you can probably just multiply the defining equation of $w(t)$ by the denominator  and differentiate both sides, for example.